# PWA Chrome cancel window.close() without alert message or default message

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

Hello we have a question about PWA and window.close events,

Before asking the question we will give some background information why we are asking this question in the first place.

We are trying to rebuild our XUL appllication to a HTML5 one with webcomponents and PWA. In this XUL Application there are allot of pop-ups with there own child windows,the user shouldn't be able to close a parent window while still having edited data inside a child window. This problem is solved when using the beforeunload event on the window object. One small problem you can't really customize this events behavior the user just gets the default message of data loss.The custom message behavior isn't available anymore because the behavior is obsolete since chrome 51.

So far the background of the problem we are trying to solve.

The question,
isn't there any setting inside the PWA manifest.json so you could ask user permission settings to be changed when the PWA is installed and run for the first time. And when this happens the user will be asked to give permission for the window.close event to be cancel-able. When doing this the user confirms to custom or none beforeunload alert pop-ups. This behavior will only be activated if the PWA is installed to the desktop of the user.

Hopefully this is or will be a option.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no permissions definition in webapp manifest.

(there is something similar for chrome extensions though)

Comment: I see but I can't find permission to cancel a window closing and how should this be used inside a PWA?

Answer (score 0):

By definition a PWA should behave as a native application, so if you are rewriting software to be a PWA you should re-model your application logic so that it stores the last state of the application on localStorage/indexedDB or similar and reads it upon starting and this would enforce the user to stay on the state you need it. No one should enforce the user to stay with the application open when they don't want.